# is it possible to read a Google Drive folder (all files) as BigQuery external data source?

Tags: google-bigquery, flysystem-google-drive

I am using Google Drive as an external data source in BigQuery. I can able to access a single file, but unable to read a folder with multiple files.

Note:
I have picked up the shareable link from Google Drive for folder and used "bq mk.." command referencing the link ID. Although it creates the table but unable to pull data.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried it with drive so I have no sense of how performant it is, but when defining an external table (or load job), you can specify the source data as a list of URIs.  My suspicion is that it's not particularly scalable and may run into limits in drive, as that's not a typical access pattern.  Google Cloud Storage is a much more suitable datasource for this kind of thing.

Comment: I agree, but I have stored few files in Google Drive folder and want to access it using BigQuery